# White text on light gray background in revisions page makes it invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the revisions tab of a post, there are timestamps of each revision. However in this specific meta site, those timestamps are not visible due to being written in white color on nearly white (#eee) background.

See for yourself: ([link](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4129/revisions))

> [image]

And when highlighting all the text (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) it finally show:

> [image]

Can one of the colors please be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay for dark themes!

Fix is in the queue and will be with you in the next build (rev 2014.2.10.1359)

Comment: Cheers, one of the fastest bug fixes! ;)

Comment: Just lucky... fix was fast and happened to be pushed just before someone wanted to build ;)

Comment: Found another place... user profile page, "less info" view - some of the text is invisible there as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - gaaah. That's gonna be somewhat more involved. Nothing good to hang the CSS off :/

Comment: Why not use `user-header-slim`? Looks like the base class for the "less view" box?

Comment: Too many things have their own styles defined inside. I'd open a new design bug so Jin can have a look.

Comment: Cheers, I'm sure Jin will solve this elegantly. :)